# onmouseover not working with React.js

Tags: reactjs

The click event works fine, but the onmouseover event does not work.

```
ProfImage = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return { showIcons: false };
    },

    onClick: function() {

        if(this.state.showIcons == true) {
            this.setState({ showIcons: false });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ showIcons: true });
        }
    },

    onHover: function() {
        this.setState({ showIcons: true });
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
            <span className="major">
                <img src="/images/profile-pic.png" height="100" onClick={this.onClick} onmouseover={this.onHover} />
            </span>


            { this.state.showIcons ? <SocialIcons /> : null }
            </div>

        );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to capitalize some of the letters.

```
<img src="/images/profile-pic.png" height="100" onClick={this.onClick} onMouseOver={this.onHover} />
```

Answer (score 17):

Both the answers above are correct, but you need to bind these method to the class context too!

```
<img src="/images/profile-pic.png" height="100" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} onMouseOver={this.onHover.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: `onMouseOver={this.onHover.bind(this, 'value')}`

Comment: uhmmm, even simpler `onMouseOver={(event) => this.onHover(event)}` , given your onHover function is also an arrow function declared as `const`