# Create React List with Remove Button on Hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a DropDown List box and each item in the list has a remove (X) button to remove the item from the list.  How is it possible to show the remove button "only" when the item is hovered over?

The current code shows the clear button each each item but I only want it to show when the item is hovered over

[image]

```
Sorry, here is the code


  import React from 'react';
   import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
   import styled from 'styled-components';

    const ListWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 16rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  } 

`;

const ListMenu = styled.div`
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background: white;
overflow-x: hidden;
`;

const ListMenuHeader = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
`;

const DropdownText = Text.Link.extend`
  padding-top: 3rem;
`;

const DropdownButton = styled.div`
  padding:  1 rem 0.75rem;
`;

const ListMenuItem = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey)};
  color: grey}; 

  >[name~=icon] {
    right: 0rem;  
    border-radius: 0;
    background: none;  
    align-items: right;
    justify-content: right;  

  &:hover {
    background-color: grey)};
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;

class ListListMenu extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
    component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,  
    selectedItem: PropTypes.any,
    getItemProps: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    highlightedIndex: PropTypes.number,
    closeListMenu: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    selectedItem: null,
    highlightedIndex: null,
  }


  onClearClick = (items,item1) => (item) => {

    const index = items.indexOf(item1);
    if (index > -1) {
        items.splice(index, 1);
   }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      id, text, items, component,  selectedItem, getItemProps,
      highlightedIndex, closeListMenu,
    } = this.props; 


    return (
      <ListWrapper id={id} >
        <ListMenuHeader onClick={closeListMenu}>
          <DropdownText>{text}</DropdownText>
          <DropdownButton
            id={`${id}-button`}
          >
            <Icon type="caret-up" appearance="neutral" />
          </DropdownButton>
        </ListMenuHeader>
        <ListMenu>
          {selectedItems.map((item, index) => (
            <ListMenuItem
              {...getItemProps({
                item,
                isActive: highlightedIndex === index,
                isSelected: _.isEqual(selectedItem, item),
              })}
              key={index} 
            >
              {React.createElement(component, { item })}


              <Button   // CLEAR BUTTON
          name={item}
          id={item}
          icon="remove"
          onClick={this.onClearClick(items, item)}
          circle
          display="flat"
          appearance="disabled"
          id="clear-search-button"          
        />

            </ListMenuItem>
          ))}


        </ListMenu>
      </ListWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default ListListMenu;
```

Comment: show the relevant code

Comment: sorry......added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you could probably just have that "x" appear on hover.

Instead of looking for a "hover" event, what about looking for an "onmouseenter" event combined with "onmouseleave"?

Like so...

```
class Example extends React.Component {

  onHover() {
    this.refs.deleteX.style.display = "block";
  }

  onExit() {
    this.refs.deleteX.style.display = "none";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onmouseenter={ this.onHover } onmouseleave={ this.onExit } />
        <p ref="deleteX">x</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Kind of like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732916/onmouseover-not-working-with-react-js)