# Check which element is hovered in React

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm building portfolio site for me with Gatsby + Wordpress. I wondered is it possible to hover name of portfolio item and image related to that?

I have idea that if `PortfolioItemNameLink` is hovered it shows image from same project. How can I check which item is hovered?

```
const PortfolioItemsText = () => {

  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        {
          allWordpressWpPortfolio {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                slug
                title
                excerpt
                content
                featured_media {
                  source_url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={props => (
        <Wrapper>
          <PortfolioImageWrapper>
            {props.allWordpressWpPortfolio.edges.map(edge => (
              <PortfolioImage
                src={edge.node.featured_media.source_url}
                alt="Thumbnail"
              />
            ))}
          </PortfolioImageWrapper>

          <PortfolioItemsWrapper>
            <PortfolioItems>
              {props.allWordpressWpPortfolio.edges.map(portfolioItem => (
                <PortfolioItem
                  style={currentStyle}
                  key={portfolioItem.node.id}
                >
                  <PortfolioItemNameLink
                    to={`/portfolio/${portfolioItem.node.slug}`}
                  >
                    <PortfolioItemNameLinkText>
                      {portfolioItem.node.title}
                    </PortfolioItemNameLinkText>
                  </PortfolioItemNameLink>
                </PortfolioItem>
              ))}
            </PortfolioItems>
          </PortfolioItemsWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default PortfolioItemsText
```

Here is screenshot from my project. When I hover title I would get right image visible and otherwise image should be not visible. 
[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By assigning a unique `key` to each item while iterating

Comment: I added keys to ```PortfolioItem``` and  ```PortfolioImage```. How I can use this to get image that belongs to hovered title?

Comment: Or how I could get data from item that I hover? ex. if I hover item which ```portfolioItem.node.title``` is Sample1 I want to get same item's ```portfolioItem.node.slug```.  By doing this I think I could somehow set right image visible when title hovered.

Comment: Can you produce code sandbox example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now working the way I want. I think I expressed my question badly. If I  hover portfolio item title I get revealed image related to that project. Image is set in the after selector. Here's my code :

```
const PortfolioItemNameLink = styled(Link)`
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: -2;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.25s linear;
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
  &:after {
    content: "";

    background-image: ${props => `url(${props.itemimage}) `};
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: 0.25s linear;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  &:hover&:after {
    opacity: 0.7;
    visibility: visible;
  }
`
```

```
 <PortfolioItemNameLink
   to={`/portfolio/${portfolioItem.node.slug}`}
   itemimage={`${portfolioItem.node.featured_media.source_url}`}
 >
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

To capture a mouse over event, you need to use the onMouseOver event. If you want to capture a mouseover event on PortfolioItemNameLinkText, your cleanest option is probably to attach that event to the outermost returned html element (doesn't need to be outermost, can be any really).
So for example, PortfolioItemNameLinkText returns:

```html
<div onMouseOver={(e)=>{console.log(this.props.children)}}>
//PortfolioItemNameLinkText code
</div>
```

Here i'm just console logging {portfolioItem.node.title} which is what your passing in as a child.

Is PortfolioItemNameLinkText a functional/stateless component? If so make sure you are passing props in correctly. eg:

```js
function PortfolioItemNameLinkText(props){//code} 
or 
const PortfolioItemNameLinkText = (props) => {//code}
```

Here is another thread showing how to use mouse events. [Mousing over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732916/onmouseover-not-working-with-react-js)

Comment: I tried this just like you showed. ```onMouseOver={(e)=>{console.log(this.props.children)}``` gives me error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined``` and if I try ```onMouseOver={(e)=>{console.log(props.children)}``` without ```this``` it logs just unidentified.

Comment: Edited original post to address props

Answer (score 0):

Passing the index to the `handleHover` and `mouseMovement` should work fine and access the array item in those functions to handle hover logic. Let me know if it works

```
<PortfolioItemsWrapper>
            <PortfolioItems>
              {props.allWordpressWpPortfolio.edges.map((portfolioItem, index) => (
                <PortfolioItem
                  style={currentStyle}
                  key={portfolioItem.node.id}
                  onMouseOver={(e) => handleHover(e, index)}
                  onMouseOut={(e) => handleLeave(e, index)}
                >
                  <PortfolioItemNameLink
                    onMouseEnter={(e) => mouseMovement(e, index)}
                    onMouseLeave={(e) => mouseMovement(e, index)}
                    to={`/portfolio/${portfolioItem.node.slug}`}
                  >
                    <PortfolioItemNameLinkText>
                      {portfolioItem.node.title}
                    </PortfolioItemNameLinkText>
                  </PortfolioItemNameLink>
                </PortfolioItem>
              ))}
            </PortfolioItems>
          </PortfolioItemsWrapper>
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.. Event handlers in my we're just some failed attempts to build element that follows mouse. I edited my post and took those away. But I also tried to add index to just this```onMouseOver={(e) => handleHover(e, index)}```. Now it's in the code and but I don't know how to use it or how this helps?

Comment: I didnot get it can you edit your comment and explain it correctly?