# How to check which element is hovered using React 17.0.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am currently trying to make a webpage that displays multiple images, and when I hover on each image, they will display different text depending on the image. I was thinking of useState and useEffect, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement that. My current structure is that I have a list with an a tag and inside that i have an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439691/5782437

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check which element is hovered in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166959/check-which-element-is-hovered-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the built in onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events and manage a state with an object containing an index of each image and its info through the events.

```
<img src={picture} onMouseEnter={() => //change the state} onMouseLeave={() => //return state back to default}></img>
```